# How to convert a string with Unicode encoding to a string of letters

Tags: java, unicode, encoding

I have a string with escaped [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters, `\uXXXX`, and I want to convert it to regular Unicode letters. For example:

```
"\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F World"
```

should become

```
"Hello World"
```

I know that when I print the first string it already shows `Hello world`. My problem is I read file names from a file, and then I search for them. The files names in the file are escaped with Unicode encoding, and when I search for the files, I can't find them, since it searches for a file with `\uXXXX` in its name.

Comment: You're sure?  You don't suppose that the characters are simply getting printed as Unicode escapes?

Comment: `\u0048` *is* `H` -- they are one and the same.  Strings in Java are in Unicode.

Comment: I guess the problem might be with my java to unix api - the string i get is something like that \u3123\u3255_file_name.txt. And java don't covert it.

Comment: Most likely you have a problem with the code page conversion when translating Java Unicode strings to the file system character set.

Comment: UTF-8 _is_ a unicode encoding.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but let me clarify the difference between Unicode and UTF-8, which many people seem to muddle up. Unicode is a particular *one-to-one* mapping between characters as we know them (`a`, `b`, `$`, `£`, etc) to the integers. E.g., the symbol `A` is given number 65, and `\n` is 10. This has *nothing* to do with how strings or characters are represented on disk or in a text file say. UTF-8 is a specification (i.e. encoding) of how these integers (i.e. symbols) are represented as bytes (bit strings) so they can be unambiguously written and read from say a file.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Technically doing:

```
String myString = "\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F World";
```

automatically converts it to `"Hello World"`, so I assume you are reading in the string from some file. In order to convert it to "Hello" you'll have to parse the text into the separate unicode digits, (take the `\uXXXX` and just get `XXXX`) then do `Integer.ParseInt(XXXX, 16)` to get a hex value and then case that to `char` to get the actual character.

**Edit: Some code to accomplish this:**

```
String str = myString.split(" ")[0];
str = str.replace("\\","");
String[] arr = str.split("u");
String text = "";
for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    int hexVal = Integer.parseInt(arr[i], 16);
    text += (char)hexVal;
}
// Text will now have Hello
```

Comment: Seems that might be the solution. Do you have an idea how can i do it in java - can i do it with String.replaceAll or something like that?

Comment: @SharonBL I updated with some code, should at least give you an idea of where to start.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help! I also found another solution for that: String s = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\\u20ac\\n"); it does the work!

Comment: This does not work for surrogate pairs at all but is ok for ASCII or 'low' code points.   Edit:  now that I think about it a bit more, it will work OK with surrogate pairs too.

Comment: attempt to reinvent methods provided by Standard Java Library. just check pure implementation https://stackoverflow.com/a/39265921/1511077

Comment: I'm always amazed when a "**reinvent the wheel**" answer gets so many votes.

Comment: Not works when there is non unicode characters inside string, such as: href=\u0022\/en\/blog\/d-day-protecting-europe-its-demons\u0022\u003E\n

Comment: @PedroLobito that's because the linked post does absolutely nothing. `myString.getBytes("UTF8")` and then back to `String` does nothing.

Comment: I agree with rustyx because `getBytes` should contain source encoding as argument, not utf-8. After that string should be created with required encoding from ByteArray.

Comment: The type `Char` is only 16 bits,  It will be overflow,if the unicode number gretter than 0XFFFF

Answer (score 113):

The [Apache Commons Lang](http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6) **StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava()** can decode it properly.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

@Test
public void testUnescapeJava() {
    String sJava="\\u0048\\u0065\\u006C\\u006C\\u006F";
    System.out.println("StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(sJava):\n" + StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(sJava));
}


 output:
 StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(sJava):
 Hello
```

Comment: String sJava="\u0048\\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F"; -----> Please do simple change.

Comment: It appears StringEscapeUtils is now located in org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils

Answer (score 35):

You can use `StringEscapeUtils` from [Apache Commons Lang](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3), i.e.:

```
String Title = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\\u0048\\u0065\\u006C\\u006C\\u006F");
```

---

Comment: after adding dependacy in build.gradle : compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'

above working fine.

Answer (score 10):

This simple method will work for most cases, but would trip up over something like "u005Cu005C" which should decode to the string "\u0048" but would actually decode "H" as the first pass produces "\u0048" as the working string which then gets processed again by the while loop.

```
static final String decode(final String in)
{
    String working = in;
    int index;
    index = working.indexOf("\\u");
    while(index > -1)
    {
        int length = working.length();
        if(index > (length-6))break;
        int numStart = index + 2;
        int numFinish = numStart + 4;
        String substring = working.substring(numStart, numFinish);
        int number = Integer.parseInt(substring,16);
        String stringStart = working.substring(0, index);
        String stringEnd   = working.substring(numFinish);
        working = stringStart + ((char)number) + stringEnd;
        index = working.indexOf("\\u");
    }
    return working;
}
```

Comment: attempt to reinvent methods provided by Standard Java Library. just check pure implementation https://stackoverflow.com/a/39265921/1511077

Comment: Thanks @EvgenyLebedev ... the standard library way looks good and presumably has been thoroughly tested, much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

With **Kotlin** you can write your own extension function for *String*

```kotlin
fun String.unescapeUnicode() = replace("\\\\u([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})".toRegex()) {
    String(Character.toChars(it.groupValues[1].toInt(radix = 16)))
}
```

and then

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val originalString = "\\u0048\\u0065\\u006C\\u006C\\u006F World"
    println(originalString.unescapeUnicode())
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Shorter version:

```
public static String unescapeJava(String escaped) {
    if(escaped.indexOf("\\u")==-1)
        return escaped;

    String processed="";

    int position=escaped.indexOf("\\u");
    while(position!=-1) {
        if(position!=0)
            processed+=escaped.substring(0,position);
        String token=escaped.substring(position+2,position+6);
        escaped=escaped.substring(position+6);
        processed+=(char)Integer.parseInt(token,16);
        position=escaped.indexOf("\\u");
    }
    processed+=escaped;

    return processed;
}
```

Comment: attempt to reinvent methods provided by Standard Java Library. just check pure implementation https://stackoverflow.com/a/39265921/1511077

Answer (score 6):

StringEscapeUtils from org.apache.commons.lang3 library is [deprecated](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.6/index.html) as of 3.6.

So you can use their new [commons-text](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/) library instead:

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.9'

OR

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
   <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Example code:

```
org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(escapedString);
```

Answer (score 5):

For Java 9+, you can use the new [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-) method of [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class.

```
private static final Pattern UNICODE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\\\u([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})");

public static String unescapeUnicode(String unescaped) {
    return UNICODE_PATTERN.matcher(unescaped).replaceAll(r -> String.valueOf((char) Integer.parseInt(r.group(1), 16)));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String originalMessage = "\\u0048\\u0065\\u006C\\u006C\\u006F World";
    String unescapedMessage = unescapeUnicode(originalMessage);
    System.out.println(unescapedMessage);
}
```

I believe the main advantage of this approach over [unescapeJava](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava(java.lang.String)) by [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html) (besides not using an extra library) is that you can convert only the unicode characters (if you wish), since the latter converts all escaped Java characters (like \n or \t). If you prefer to convert all escaped characters the library is really the best option.

Answer (score 4):

It's not totally clear from your question, but I'm assuming you saying that you have a file where each line of that file is a filename.  And each filename is something like this:

```
\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F
```

In other words, the characters in the file of filenames are `\`, `u`, `0`, `0`, `4`, `8` and so on.

If so, what you're seeing is expected.  Java only translates `\uXXXX` sequences in string literals in source code (and when reading in stored `Properties` objects).  When you read the contents you file you will have a string consisting of the characters `\`, `u`, `0`, `0`, `4`, `8` and so on and **not** the string `Hello`.

So you will need to parse that string to extract the `0048`, `0065`, etc. pieces and then convert them to `char`s and make a string from those `char`s and then pass that string to the routine that opens the file.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to contribute my version, using regex:

```
private static final String UNICODE_REGEX = "\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})";
private static final Pattern UNICODE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(UNICODE_REGEX);
...
String message = "\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F World";
Matcher matcher = UNICODE_PATTERN.matcher(message);
StringBuffer decodedMessage = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
  matcher.appendReplacement(
      decodedMessage, String.valueOf((char) Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1), 16)));
}
matcher.appendTail(decodedMessage);
System.out.println(decodedMessage.toString());
```

Comment: The regex is not complete. The regex referenced by Marcelo for the Java 9+ solution will work in this case for Java 8
`"\\\\u([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})"`

Answer (score 3):

Updates regarding answers suggesting using The Apache Commons Lang's:
 [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava-java.lang.String-) - it was deprecated,

> **Deprecated.** 
>   as of 3.6, use commons-text StringEscapeUtils instead

The replacement is **Apache Commons Text**'s [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 2):

one easy way i know using JsonObject:

```
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("string", myString);
    String converted = json.getString("string");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a performanced and error-proof solution:

```
public static final String decode(final String in) {
    int p1 = in.indexOf("\\u");
    if (p1 < 0)
        return in;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (true) {
        int p2 = p1 + 6;
        if (p2 > in.length()) {
            sb.append(in.subSequence(p1, in.length()));
            break;
        }
        try {
            int c = Integer.parseInt(in.substring(p1 + 2, p1 + 6), 16);
            sb.append((char) c);
            p1 += 6;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            sb.append(in.subSequence(p1, p1 + 2));
            p1 += 2;
        }
        int p0 = in.indexOf("\\u", p1);
        if (p0 < 0) {
            sb.append(in.subSequence(p1, in.length()));
            break;
        } else {
            sb.append(in.subSequence(p1, p0));
            p1 = p0;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`UnicodeUnescaper`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/translate/UnicodeUnescaper.html) from Apache Commons Text does exactly what you want, and ignores any other escape sequences.

```java
String input = "\\u0048\\u0065\\u006C\\u006C\\u006F World";
String output = new UnicodeUnescaper().translate(input);
assert("Hello World".equals(output));
assert("\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F World".equals(output));
```

Where `input` would be the string you are reading from a file.

Answer (score 1):

Fast

```
 fun unicodeDecode(unicode: String): String {
        val stringBuffer = StringBuilder()
        var i = 0
        while (i < unicode.length) {
            if (i + 1 < unicode.length)
                if (unicode[i].toString() + unicode[i + 1].toString() == "\\u") {
                    val symbol = unicode.substring(i + 2, i + 6)
                    val c = Integer.parseInt(symbol, 16)
                    stringBuffer.append(c.toChar())
                    i += 5
                } else stringBuffer.append(unicode[i])
            i++
        }
        return stringBuffer.toString()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
private static final Charset UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
private String forceUtf8Coding(String input) {return new String(input.getBytes(UTF_8), UTF_8))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I wrote an Open Source library that contains some utilities. One of them is converting a Unicode sequence to String and vise-versa. I found it very useful. Here is the quote from the article about this library about Unicode converter:

> Class StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder has methods that can convert a
>   String (in any language) into a sequence of Unicode characters and
>   vise-versa. For example a String "Hello World" will be converted into
>
> "\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020 \u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064"
>
> and may be restored back.

Here is the link to entire article that explains what Utilities the library has and how to get the library to use it. It is available as Maven artifact or as source from Github. It is very easy to use. [Open Source Java library with stack trace filtering, Silent String parsing Unicode converter and Version comparison](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution...

```
                String decodedName = JwtJson.substring(startOfName, endOfName);

                StringBuilder builtName = new StringBuilder();

                int i = 0;

                while ( i < decodedName.length() )
                {
                    if ( decodedName.substring(i).startsWith("\\u"))
                    {
                        i=i+2;
                        builtName.append(Character.toChars(Integer.parseInt(decodedName.substring(i,i+4), 16)));
                        i=i+4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        builtName.append(decodedName.charAt(i));
                        i = i+1;
                    }
                };
```

Comment: attempt to reinvent standard methods provided by Standard Java Library. just check pure implementation https://stackoverflow.com/a/39265921/1511077

Answer (score 0):

I found that many of the answers did not address the issue of "Supplementary Characters". Here is the correct way to support it. No third-party libraries, pure Java implementation.

http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/supplementary-142654.html

```
public static String fromUnicode(String unicode) {
    String str = unicode.replace("\\", "");
    String[] arr = str.split("u");
    StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int hexVal = Integer.parseInt(arr[i], 16);
        text.append(Character.toChars(hexVal));
    }
    return text.toString();
}

public static String toUnicode(String text) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        int codePoint = text.codePointAt(i);
        // Skip over the second char in a surrogate pair
        if (codePoint > 0xffff) {
            i++;
        }
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(codePoint);
        sb.append("\\u");
        for (int j = 0; j < 4 - hex.length(); j++) {
            sb.append("0");
        }
        sb.append(hex);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

@Test
public void toUnicode() {
    System.out.println(toUnicode(""));
    System.out.println(toUnicode(""));
    System.out.println(toUnicode("Hello World"));
}
// output:
// \u1f60a
// \u1f970
// \u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064

@Test
public void fromUnicode() {
    System.out.println(fromUnicode("\\u1f60a"));
    System.out.println(fromUnicode("\\u1f970"));
    System.out.println(fromUnicode("\\u0048\\u0065\\u006c\\u006c\\u006f\\u0020\\u0057\\u006f\\u0072\\u006c\\u0064"));
}
// output:
// 
// 
// Hello World
```

Comment: Not works when there is non unicode characters inside string, such as: href=\u0022\/en\/blog\/d-day-protecting-europe-its-demons\u0022\u003E\n

Answer (score 0):

@NominSim
There may be other character, so I should detect it by length.

```
private String forceUtf8Coding(String str) {
    str = str.replace("\\","");
    String[] arr = str.split("u");
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
        String a = arr[i];
        String b = "";
        if (arr[i].length() > 4){
            a = arr[i].substring(0, 4);
            b = arr[i].substring(4);
        }
        int hexVal = Integer.parseInt(a, 16);
        text.append((char) hexVal).append(b);
    }
    return text.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, no need to depend 3-part library. Just use the java built-in library.

Assuming that we have a unicode '1F914',

1. firstly we convert it from hex to decimal using `Integer.parseInt`
2. then we pass the decimal representation to `Character.toChars()`, got a char array.

> Java use UTF-16 to encode String. If a character that codepoint is over than 16 bit, using a char array to represent it.

3. After that,we new a sting by the char array. Finally we got a emoji : “”

```java
new String(Character.toChars(Integer.parseInt(unicode, 16)));
```

Answer (score -1):

An alternate way of accomplishing this could be to make use of [**`chars()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#chars()) introduced with Java 9, this can be used to iterate over the characters making sure any char which maps to a [surrogate code point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode) is passed through uninterpreted. This can be used as:-

```
String myString = "\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F World";
myString.chars().forEach(a -> System.out.print((char)a));
// would print "Hello World"
```

Comment: So would just `System.out.println("\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F World")`

Answer (score -2):

**Solution for Kotlin:**

```
val sourceContent = File("test.txt").readText(Charset.forName("windows-1251"))
val result = String(sourceContent.toByteArray())
```

Kotlin uses UTF-8 everywhere as default encoding.

Method `toByteArray()` has default argument - `Charsets.UTF_8`.

Comment: `String(string.toByteArray())` achieves literally nothing.

Comment: @rustyx Method `toByteArray()` has default argument with `Charsets.UTF_8`. Then you create a string from bytearray with required encoding. I did test today with `windows-1251` to utf-8, it works. Also i did comparison at byte level :)

Comment: @rustyx here is a gist for you - https://gist.github.com/lebe-dev/31e31a3399c7885e298ed86810504676