# Decode and Decode UTF-8 with Java

Tags: java, unicode

I'm have a problem to decode and encode String,

My program reads String Value `Hungr\u00EDa` from Response webservice, and then i need translate this value to `Hungría`.. I can't understand how to works. but when I send string into webservice request I need encode the value `Hungría` to  `Hungr\u00EDa`.

```
String input = "Hungr\u00EDa";
logger.info("UTF8test.decodeUTF8: "+new String(input.getBytes(),Charset.forName("UTF-8"))); //output is Hungr?a, updated to UTF-8
```

Comment: That's not character-encoded in a different encoding. That's just an unicode codepoint in string format.

Comment: `UTF8-8` is that correct?

Comment: shouldn't `UTF8-8` be `UTF-8`?

Comment: When I run that code, I get the desired output, but I'm not using `logger`. Maybe `logger` doesn't know how to handle the unicode character?

Comment: "but when i'm send string into webservice request I need encode the value Hungría to Hungr\u00EDa" - is it a JSON request then? If so, use a JSON library. It's quite unclear exactly what you mean at the moment - but you should *not* be re-encoding the string in the way you currently are.

Comment: Your question is similar to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters

Comment: the server side, reads Hungr\u00EDa has String

Comment: `"Hungr\u00EDa".length()` is 7, and not 12. Are you misunderstanding something?

Comment: Chriss, Thanks the similar post is exactly my problem, there is my solution. thanks a lot. sorry to all for my bad interpretation about the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the impression you are not yet clear on what UTF-8 is, and what it isn't.

Most likely, the output actually is in UTF-8 (at least if you fix your typo. Consider using shorter lines, too!). But `Hungr\u00EDa` **is not UTF-8**. `Hungría` is, assuming that you access stackoverflow in UTF-8. What `\u00ED` is is *not* UTF-8. It is an **different encoding based on UTF-8**, I would call this "backslash-escaped-unicode". See: `00ED` is probably the hexadecimal *unicode* character code of the character you want. The UTF-8 encoding of this character is the two bytes `0xC3 0xAD`, while in HTML it would be encoded as `&#237;`.