# android long dash in string in code

Tags: java, android

I am trying to put a long dash "—" between two words in String in my Android project. For example something like this:

```
Name — Surname
```

The String will be converted in code, not in **xml**. The only way i found to do this, is converting String to **HTML** and back. Like this:

```
stringBuilder.append(Name).append(" & mdash; ").append(Surname);  
Html.fromHtml(stringBuilder.toString()).toString();
```

(Space between "&" and "mdash;" to prevent convertation on stackoverflow).
 
Can it be done more elegant, without converting to **HTML** and back?
 Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have you tried unicode notation `\u2014`?

Reference: [How to convert a string with Unicode encoding to a string of letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters)

Comment: Sorry for such a long answer. Yes, It works, thanks). Now will try to find how to mark that answer is correct)