# How do i convert hex to binary in java?

Tags: java, hex, binary-data, unicode-escapes

I have a string:

```
l="\u00d0\u00a2\u00d0\u00b0".
```

I want to convert it into binary data. I have tried this:

```
int c = Integer.parseInt(l,16);
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(c));
```

But i get the error:

```
" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string" exception.
```

Comment: Everything in a computer is binary data!  :- )

Comment: Have you seen this question and its answers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters