# unicode converting in RestTemplate in Spring

Tags: java, spring, unicode, utf-8

My aim is getting user info by accessToken using facebook api.I get response but email in this response is like this:
aaaaaa\u0040mail.com.

For converting i add some properties but this doesn't work

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

String facebook = restTemplate.getForObject(
            "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + facebookAccessToken,
            String.class);
```

How can i convet this email to:
aaaaaa@mail.com

Comment: Little dirty, but could just `facebook = facebook.replace("\u0040","@")`

Comment: no.this doesn't work me because @ in email is one of the problem.i need ə ğ ü etc. Azerbaijani Latin alphabets too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/). There's a [method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html) called `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(String s)` That can do it.

(From https://stackoverflow.com/a/14368185/1176061)