# Representing ^A (Unicode \u0001) correctly in Java when passed as argument

Tags: java, unicode, special-characters

```
 public class TestU {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "\u0001";
        System.out.println("str-->"+str);
        System.out.println("arg[0]-->"+args[0]);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
str-->^A
arg[0]-->\u0001
```

I am passing `arg[0]` as `\u0001`

I executed this code in linux, the command line variable is not taken as unicode special character.

Comment: Your commandline argument takes string array as input and hence treat it as a String.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters

Answer (score 2):

The argument you pass from command line is not actually unicode character but it's a `String` of unicode character which is escaped with `\`. Ultimately, your String will become `\\u0001` and that's why it is printing `\u0001`. Same way, if you enter `\` as a command line argument it will become `\\` to escape your backward slash.

While the `String` you have declared in main is actually unicode character.

```
String escapedstring = "\\u0001";//in args[0]
String unicodeChar = "\u0001";// in str
```

So, now you want `\\u0001` to be converted into `\u0001` and there are lot of ways to achieve that. *i.e.* you can use [`StringEscapeUtils#unescapeJava`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava(java.lang.String)) method of utility or you can also try following way.

```
String str = "\\u0001";
char unicodeChar = (char) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(2));
System.out.println(unicodeChar);
```

*NOTE* : You can find other ways to convert unicode String to unicode characters in following question.(Already provided in comment by `Marcinek`)

- [How to convert a string with Unicode encoding to a string of letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters)

Comment: Ok. Somewhere I am getting this  values \u0001 I need this to be behave as unicode and not as string \u0001 , beacause I need to use this special character as delimieter to write into file but presently its writing as A\u0001B it should be A^AB where A and B is the data for two columns respectively