# how can i replace unicode String in url for getting json response?

Tags: java, android, json, unicode

I have a this api from aparat site . I use this method for search

`http://www.aparat.com/etc/api/videoBySearch/text/[نوروز]`

I should fill last parameter with my `editText` value . For getting json . If i send `english` string it worked . But if i send unicode string like `persian` , It can't work and when i logging that , it say

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL null

This is my JsonResponse method :

```
   //this method call when search button pressed !
    private void sendJsonRequest() {
        String rawQuery = edtsearchQuery.getText().toString();
       ==> String first_url =   "http://www.aparat.com/etc/api/videoBySearch/text/"+ rawQuery;



        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, first_url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                parseJsonResponse(response);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("onErrorResponseSenJsReq" , error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
```

Comment: In which language api is developed?

Comment: i think php .  this site is public and i cant access to site code

Comment: either encode as  @ρяσѕρєя-k suggested. alternatively you can try sending as `POST`  instead of `GET`

Comment: Did you take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of sending `نوروز` in URL use `URLEncoder` for encoding it before appending it in main URL:

```
String strSearchQuery= URLEncoder.encode(rawQuery, "utf-8");
String first_url="http://www.aparat.com/etc/api/videoBySearch/text/"
                                                        +strSearchQuery;
```

Comment: according to your sulution  . it's replaced but it still have a problem and when i enter the value of mu url it worked on chrome . but it didnt work on mobile .

Comment: While `String strSearchQuery= URLEncoder.encode(rawQuery, "utf-8");` is more readable, it is worth knowing that it is equivalent to  `String strSearchQuery= URLEncoder.encode(rawQuery);`

Comment: with english string  http://www.aparat.com//etc/api/videobysearch/text/b/curoffset/20 and with unicode string http://www.aparat.com//etc/api/videobysearch/text/%D9%86%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B2/curoffset/20

Comment: @kianarahimi: but `http://www.aparat.com/etc/api/videoBySearch/text/%D9%86%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B2` url is working as get request when im trying it

Comment: @kianarahimi: Welcome Dear.

Comment: can i have you skpe id :D