# python3: How to convert a string with Unicode encoding to a string of letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

In Python3, how do I convert `'\\u00A9 PNG'` to `'\u00A9 PNG'` (or `'© PNG'`)?

For Java, there is [Apache Commons Lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters) to decode it.

I don't know how to do in Python3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
string = '\\u00A9 PNG'
print (string.encode('utf8').decode('unicode-escape'))
```

output:

> © PNG