# Java: Display unicode chars as chars when printing string

Tags: java, json, unicode, char, wikipedia

I have some code that retrieves a Wikipedia summary for a given query and it pulls the information from the Wikipedia JSON api. See the code [here](https://gist.github.com/schwartzadev/95ff8e00e4a9338b6e3e003df328eaf5) (gist.github.com). Wikipedia's API returns characters in this form: `\u026al` or `\u0259` as well as `\n`. Right now when I print the output, something like the following is returned: `Hillary Clinton (5043192): Hillary Diane Rodham Clinton (/\u02c8h\u026al\u0259ri da\u026a\u02c8\u00e6n \u02c8r\u0252d\u0259m \u02c8kl\u026ant\u0259n/; born October 26, 1947) is an American politician who...`. How can I have the unicode characters be printed as such instead of printing their codes?

Comment: [`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava(java.lang.String))

Comment: This problem was already solved. Have a look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11145854/7313233.