# Why java string display \u on screen

Tags: java, unicode

Suppose \u4404 means 'A' in Japanese.
Following code will print 'A' on screen.

```
String str = "\u4404";
System.out.println(str);
```

This is true because `encode("\u4404", unicode)='A'`.

But I encountered one problem. When I process a message received over http, I get following output like

`{"name":"\u4404\u2424\u4022","age":"30"}`

The http header shows the reply is encoded by utf-8. But why does the ouput shows like this?

Here is my guess:
Suppose the stream I received from web is `mystream`. Then, after we encode `mystream` with `utf-8`, I get `\u4404\u2424\u4022`. I have to encode `mystream` by TWO times, and get the right 'A' in Japanes.

Am I right? If i am right, why transfer data like this? Because of JSON? Thans very much for your ansewer!

Comment: Might be a bug on their end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a string with Unicode encoding to a string of letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters)

Comment: "When I process a message received over http, I get following output like" - what sort of processing? It's very unclear whether you're writing the server or the client, where you're seeing that "output" etc. Please provide a *lot* more context.

Comment: When you say "A" do you mean "あ"?