# how to convert unicode characters to actual characters in java?

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, url-encoding

I have to two strings :
1. bookkeeping forms \\u0026 templates
2. hodgkin\u0027s disease

I want to replace \\u0026 with & and \u0027 with '. One of the way is replace their occurrence with corresponding symbol but is there a generic way to deal with this problem ?

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters

Comment: Where are these strings? Where do they come from?

Comment: they are coming as json from an http request.

Comment: Then the JSON parser will transform those escape sequences to characters automatically.

Comment: Why does one of the escape sequences start with a double backslash and the other one with a single backslash? What's the difference?

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is Apache `StringScapeUtils` specifically the `unescapeJava` method.

**Site:** https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

**Maven repo:** https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3

[image]

That method converts unicode to readable text, for example:

```
String stringWithUnicode; //For example "tendr\\u00e1"
StringScapeUtils.unescapeJava(stringWithUnicode); //This call returns: Tendrá
```

Comment: In your example, there should be two `\ `s in the string literal, otherwise you may as well use the literal by itself.

Comment: Your code example should be using a double backslash `StringScapeUtils.unescapeJava("\\u00e1");` , otherwise the string literal already contains the single character `á`, unescaped by the Java compiler.