# Replace Unicode \u texts in String with Java

Tags: java, regex

I have this sample `String` with `Cooking \u0026 Baking Needs \u002A` text having Unicodes what is the best way to replace all Unicodes with actual String? Like replace `\0026` with `&` etc.

This is my initial code:

```
public static String tidy(String s) {
    String unicodeCharRegex = "\\\\u[A-Fa-f\\d]{4}\n";
    if(s != null && !s.isEmpty()) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(unicodeCharRegex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while(m.find()) {

        }
    }
    return s;
}

private String unicodeToString(String u) { 
    // TODO:
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the below [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters):

```
private String unicodeToString(String u) { 

String str = u.split(" ")[0];
str = str.replace("\\","");
String[] arr = str.split("u");
String text = "";
for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    int hexVal = Integer.parseInt(arr[i], 16);
    text += (char)hexVal;
}

  return text;
}
```

Comment: why did you just copy the code from the accepted answer of a duplicate?

Comment: Thanks nice it worked.