# Export CSV file using GWT Framework

Tags: java

I would like to know that I export csv file using String Builder in GWT Framework, it's fine. But when I open my csv file,some field are shown as String and some field are show as UNICODE.I want to show as String fields not UNICODE.What should I do? Please support for my question.

Comment: Please post your code so we can help. We can't be much help without being able to read your code and see where the problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a string with Unicode encoding to a string of letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters)