# How do I resolve a string that has unicode characters written in that way: \u003C, \u0022

Tags: java, string, unicode, decode

I have string which contains substrings like `\u0022`, `\u003C`, `\n` and want to replace them by the characters they stand for. What's the most straight forward way? Of course I could do something like

```
code = code.replaceAll("\\\\u003C", "<");
```

for each such character, but that's a little bit annoying.

**Edit:** To make it clear, I have already a string like

```
code="Hello \\u0022 World \\n \\u003C And so on.";
```

Comment: Hope you can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters

Comment: Probably you can find solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters

Comment: @darshakat I have to admit, you have the fastest hand on the wild west

Comment: I have read those threads before I posted this here. But the strings there are different from mine. I actually have `\u0022` as substring (this are six characters). In the examples `\u0022` is only one character.

Comment: The dupe goes over your exact situation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14368185/485343) for example.

Comment: @rustyx Is there a solution without Apache Commons Lang?

Comment: @rustyx Could you please reopen my question? My question is different from the linked one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    String str = "unicodedString=Hello \\u0022 World \\n \\u003C And so on.";
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(str);
    properties.load(stringReader);
    System.out.println(properties.getProperty("unicodedString"));
}
```

**output**

```
Hello " World 
 < And so on.
```

Comment: Your string is the wrong string to start with. Use double backslash to get a string of my kind.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain I have updated my answer , let me know if it works for u.

Comment: In your answer you're reading the String from a file. In my case I have it already stored in a string. How would I do it then?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain check updated answer

Comment: Thank you. Your current answer version solves my problem!