# How to recover a String in Java (decoding)?

Tags: java, string, obfuscation, decoding, recover

In java I have the following String:

\ud55c\u0022\u0325\u0333\u033a\u0356\u0325\u035a\u0325\u035a...

Well actually in the code it goes on for way longer, but this is because it is obfuscated. I wonder if it is possible to recover such strings. I tried UTF, ASCII, ISO encodings but they all give invalid strings. I am trying to make a plugin for a program using bytecode manipulation. All the annotations appear like tremendously large String as shown above however.

Comment: So basicly you're looking for a deobfuscator? Here is a list of different ones from a while back: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1370/what-is-a-good-java-decompiler-and-deobfuscator

Comment: Looks like unicode in Java, do some digging in that direction.

Comment: `\u0022` for example is the unicode for [quotation mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22/index.htm).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters

Comment: I've tried multiple deobfuscators; they did not work. I already knew it was unicode hence I tried to use the encodings. The link that is given by Uriel Frankel crashed the program.