# Handling unicode escaping in Java InputStream

Tags: java, unicode

I am reading json files to String, I sometimes update them (replace some specific words by others) and then write those update json files in a zip.
This is what an example input file looks like:
[image]

The issue is, the output "loses" character escaping and is therefore no longer a valid json:
[image]

To read the json:

```java
    private InputStream processJsonFile(File file) throws IOException {
        String content;
        if (!file.exists())
            return new ByteArrayInputStream("".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        try {
            content = IOUtils.toString(new FileReader(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
            Logs.logError("Error while reading file " + file.getPath());
            Logs.logError("It seems to be malformed!");
            return new ByteArrayInputStream("".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly();
        }

        // here i do things with content

        return new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
```

to add an inputstream to the zip file:

```java
  try (fis) {
            while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0)
                zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
        }
```

Comment: Mayber this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters

Comment: Hmm I tried ``content = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(content);`` but this escaped everything so this is no longer a valid json

Comment: `// here i do things with content` …Whatever things you’re doing have resulted in something that is no longer valid JSON.  From [the JSON specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159.html#section-7):  “A string begins and ends with quotation marks.  All Unicode characters may be placed within the quotation marks, except for the characters that must be escaped: quotation mark, reverse solidus, **and the control characters (U+0000 through U+001F).**”  If you put a character in the 00-1f range in your string, it *must* be expressed as a Unicode escape sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You're outputting raw Unicode values, when you should be encoding them as Unicode constants eg `\unnnn`.

Use a library to encode the content, eg

```
content = EntityUtils.toString(content,"UTF-8");
```

Comment: it seems that EntityUtils takes a HTTPEntity and not a String

Comment: The best way would be to read it in as a json object, modify it, then deserialise it to a string using ObjectMapper.