# How do I convert Unicode U+xxxx representation of an emoji into the emoji in Java?

Tags: java

I have a string with Unicode representation of emoji like this:

"Hello U+1F601"

I want to convert this into:

"Hello "

I have tried decoding them using the `parseInt()` method and converting it to `char`, but I keep getting a black and white glyph like this - .

Any pointers how can I can achieve the intended result with Java?

P.S: `unescapeJava()` method doesn't work here. I have tried it and also some other answers from other similar threads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string with Unicode encoding to a string of letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters)

Comment: @f1sh unfortunately no, I have gone through the answers but the problem here is I have to display an emoji and not normal characters. The unescapeJava() method or the other codes don't help.

Answer (score 5):

U+1F601 describes [a Unicode codepoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Codespace_and_Code_Points).

*Often* when you want to convert a codepoint to a `String` in Java then what you describe will work.

*However* it only works when the codepoint is in [the Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), which basically means it's smaller than U+10000 (i.e. at most 4 hex digits). The BMP includes *most* frequently used characters, but is notably *not* home to many newer emojis.

If it's above that point, then you need to use two `char` values to combine into a single codepoint with [some math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_from_U+010000_to_U+10FFFF).

Luckily you don't have to do that math on your own, but can use [this version of `Character.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)) instead:

```
Character.toString(0x1F601);
```

And to fully implement the replacement, we can simply [use `Matcher.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)):

```
String input = "Hello U+1F601";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("U\\+([0-9a-fA-F]{4,6})");
String result = p.matcher(input).replaceAll(r -> Character.toString(Integer.parseInt(r.group(1), 16)));
System.out.println(result);
```