# How to convert unicode text to readable text

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, charset

I use `UrlFetch` to get web content in Google AppsScript.
Problem is that the content I get is:
`Kurulu\u015f Osman - \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0624\u0633\u0633 \u0639\u062b\u0645\u0627\u0646`

When I use Logger.log(content) I get:
`Kuruluş Osman - المؤسس عثمان`
This is what I want to get when I do a POST UrlFetchApp.

When I POST the content with `UrlFetchApp.fetch(content)` I still get:
`Kurulu\u015f Osman - \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0624\u0633\u0633 \u0639\u062b\u0645\u0627\u0646`

How to get the Logger.log(content) also being POST:ed with UrlFetchApp command?

Code:

```
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlA).getContentText(); // Gives, in Debug mode: Kurulu\u015f Osman - \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0624\u0633\u0633 \u0639\u062b\u0645\u0627\u0646
Logger.log(result); // Gives: Kuruluş Osman - المؤسس عثمان

var payload = JSON.stringify({content: result});
var params = {
    method: "POST",
    payload: payload,
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    contentType: "application/json"
};

UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlB, params);
```

I get this at the receiving end: `Kurulu\u015f Osman - \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0624\u0633\u0633 \u0639\u062b\u0645\u0627\u0646`

Comment: [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: I formatted your code a bit; please consider than on future posts - and feel free to update my super fast edit as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You have [multiple ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters) of doing so.

The thing is that Unicode is decoded to avoid compatibility errors with different platforms you may want to check your logs in.

It is widespread to have consoles that only support ASCII, for example.

My suggestion is to streamline your logs. I know that this can be annoying, but as soon as you get used to a log platform (Datadog, Sentry, PaperTrail...) this goes always.

Comment: I have looked at the [multiple ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145681/how-to-convert-a-string-with-unicode-encoding-to-a-string-of-letters).
I can't find any suitable way to make it happend in GAS. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
Updated Solution coded by myself. Please comment.
```

```
function fixText(content) {

 var regex1 = /(\\)u([0-9A-Fa-f]){4}/gm;
 var findChar = [...content.matchAll(regex1)];
 var nbroffindChar = findChar.length;
 var outPutLenght = content.length;
 var count = 0;

if(nbroffindChar >0){
  
 for(b=0;b<nbroffindChar;b++){
      
  var text = content.substring(count,outPutLenght);
  var check = text.search(regex1);    
  var code = text.substring(check + 2,check + 6);
  var hexToDec = parseInt(code, 16);
  var char = String.fromCharCode(hexToDec);
  var textOutput = content.replace(code, char); 
      
  count = check + 1; 
  content = textOutput;

 }

  var regex2 = /(\\)u/gm;
  textOutput = textOutput.replace(regex2, "");
  content = textOutput;

 }

  return content;

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).